# Iterating within groups until a column changes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following input df:

```
    domain      ip      timestamp
0   Google      101     2020-04-01 23:01:41
1   Google      101     2020-04-01 23:01:59
2   Google      101     2020-04-02 12:01:41
3   Facebook    101     2020-04-02 13:11:33
4   Facebook    101     2020-04-02 13:11:35
5   Youtube     103     2020-04-21 13:01:41
6   Youtube     103     2020-04-21 13:11:46
7   Youtube     103     2020-04-22 01:01:01
8   Google      103     2020-04-22 02:11:23
9   Facebook    103     2020-04-23 14:11:13
10  Youtube     103     2020-04-23 14:11:55
```

How can I get this output? Where `domain_num` is an iterator that increases everytime a domain switches within an IP.

```
    domain      ip      timestamp             domain_num
0   Google      101     2020-04-01 23:01:41   1
1   Google      101     2020-04-01 23:01:59   1
2   Google      101     2020-04-02 12:01:41   1
3   Facebook    101     2020-04-02 13:11:33   2
4   Facebook    101     2020-04-02 13:11:35   2
5   Youtube     103     2020-04-21 13:01:41   1
6   Youtube     103     2020-04-21 13:11:46   1
7   Youtube     103     2020-04-22 01:01:01   1
8   Google      103     2020-04-22 02:11:23   2
9   Facebook    103     2020-04-23 14:11:13   3
10  Youtube     103     2020-04-23 14:11:55   4
```

I tried something like this which gets the counts but I need to group it by ip

```
df['domain'].ne(df['domain'].shift()).cumsum()
```

This code below errors out

```
df.groupby('ip').apply(lambda x : x[x.domain.ne(x.domain.shift().cumsum())])
```

**Data**

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'domain':['Google', 'Google', 'Google', 'Facebook', 'Facebook', 'Youtube', 'Youtube', 'Youtube', 'Google', 'Facebook', 'Youtube'],
        'ip':[101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103, 103],
        'timestamp' : ['2020-04-01 23:01:41', '2020-04-01 23:01:59', '2020-04-02 12:01:41', '2020-04-02 13:11:33',
        '2020-04-02 13:11:35', '2020-04-21 13:01:41', '2020-04-21 13:11:46', 
                       '2020-04-22 01:01:01', '2020-04-22 02:11:23','2020-04-23 14:11:13', '2020-04-23 14:11:55' ]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['timestamp']= pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
```

Comment: is `ip` monotonic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume your dataframe is sorted by `timestamp` column:

```
inc_domain_num = lambda x: x.ne(x.shift()).cumsum()
df['domain_num'] = df.groupby('ip')['domain'].apply(inc_domain_num)
print(df)

# Output
      domain   ip           timestamp  domain_num
0     Google  101 2020-04-01 23:01:41           1
1     Google  101 2020-04-01 23:01:59           1
2     Google  101 2020-04-02 12:01:41           1
3   Facebook  101 2020-04-02 13:11:33           2
4   Facebook  101 2020-04-02 13:11:35           2
5    Youtube  103 2020-04-21 13:01:41           1
6    Youtube  103 2020-04-21 13:11:46           1
7    Youtube  103 2020-04-22 01:01:01           1
8     Google  103 2020-04-22 02:11:23           2
9   Facebook  103 2020-04-23 14:11:13           3
10   Youtube  103 2020-04-23 14:11:55           4
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `ip` is grouped properly (not necessarily in sorted order), first find all the locations that you want to increment at:

```
df['domain_num'] = (df['domain'] != df['domain'].shift(1)) | (df['ip'] != df['ip'].shift(1))
```

Now replace that with the cumulative sum, but independently for each group:

```
df['domain_num'] = df.groupby('ip')['domain_num'].cumsum()
```